# Passing a variable from response to request in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

So I have the following response after login:

```
       Response Data: {"status":"ok","userId":"GTBA6520506207","token":"74bb0ba8be426d50"}
Request type : POST
```

I need to form my Regular expression extractor. What should be the parameters? I am using the following:

```
Reference name : token
Regular expression : "$token":"(.+?)"
Template: $1$.
```

Sample Request header:

```
Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: ****************/
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
X-Token: 59d7ff6833495fcc
X-User-Id: R1RCQTY1MjA1MDYyMDc=
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Host: **************
```

The token changes on each login for the login page in Jmeter but for all the other pages the token remains the same and it is not changing. What should I do to solve that?

Jmeter Results Tree:

Login Page - (Token changes on each Jmeter run)

Page 1  Page 2 & Page 3 - Token remains the same.

Thank you

Comment: Please show your test plan, also do you assign token variable in another place as user parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) as a child of the first request and configure it as follows:

   - Reference Name: `token`
   - JSON Path Expressions: `$.token`
   - other fields can be left as they are
2. Add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) as a child of the 2nd request and configure it to send the following headers:

   - `X-Token` with the value of `${token}`
   - `X-User-Id` with the value of `${__base64Encode(GTBA6520506207,)}`

You need to have [Custom JMeter Functions](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/) plugin bundle to be installed in order to have [__base64Encode() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Encodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup), you can install Custom JMeter Functions using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager).

---

If for some reason you cannot use JMeter Plugins you can encode your username using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like

```
${__groovy('GTBA6520506207'.bytes.encodeBase64() as String,)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following expression,
**Reference name :** token
**Regular expression :** "token":"(.+?)"
**Template:** $1$

The above expression will work fine. 
"${token}" is used to call the loaded token value.

You can also get your work done by using JSON Path Extractor.

Expression for JSON Path Extractor,

**Variable names:** token
**JSON Path expression:** $..token
**Match No. :** -1
**Default Value**: 0

Here ${token} is used to call the value of token wherever required.

[JSON Path Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)